# Getting UndeclaredThrowableException instead of my own exception

Tags: java, aop, aspect

I have the following code

```
public Object handlePermission(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RequirePermission permission) throws AccessException, Throwable {
    System.out.println("Permission = " + permission.value());
    if (user.hasPermission(permission.value())) {
        System.out.println("Permission granted ");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Permission");
        throw new AccessException("Current user does not have required permission");
    }

}
```

When I use a user that does not have permissions, I get `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException` instead of `AccessException`.

Comment: [When Does Java Throw UndeclaredThrowableException? | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-undeclaredthrowableexception)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`AccessException` is a checked exception, but it was thrown from the method that doesn't declare it in its `throws` clause (actually - from the aspect intercepting that method). It's an abnormal condition in Java, so your exception is wrapped with `UndeclaredThrowableException`, which is unchecked.

To get your exception as is, you can either declare it in the `throws` clause of the method being intercepted by your aspect, or use another unchecked exception (i.e. a subclass of `RuntimeException`) instead of `AccessException`.

Comment: +1. I would only add that in these situations `UndeclaredThrowableException` wraps the original exception; `getCause()` will return `AccessException`.

Comment: I had declared AccessException in the method that intercepts. Changing AccessException to extend RuntimeException worked.

Comment: If you're the author of the code that is being caught with `UndeclaredThrowableException` it might be good to read [this post that has some details](http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/java-proxies-and-undeclaredthrowableexception/)

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg and anyone else, I think I was caught out by the proxy issue but then used throw new `ValidationException('delete.failure',s.errors)`  - this then returned correct message instead of `UndeclaredThrowableException` which is what `RuntimeException` was returning

Comment: In my case declaring `throws ClassNotFoundException` in the method didn't work but wrapping the exception inside a `RuntimeException` did help (`throw new RuntimeException(e)`). For some context: I was using it inside a gradle `@TaskAction` annotated method

Comment: This link is equally important https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715298/dynamic-proxy-and-checked-exceptions