# Getting UndeclaredThrowableException in a Thrift call

Tags: java, exception, thrift, dynamic-proxy

I am getting this

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getMyObject(Unknown Source)
```

I went through a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490139/getting-undeclaredthrowableexception-instead-of-my-own-exception) and [this](http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/java-proxies-and-undeclaredthrowableexception/) article posted in one the comments .

But in this case the I am calling following method using a `ThriftClient` which was created using `com.twitter.common.thrift.ThriftFactory<T>`

```
myThriftClient.getMyObject()
```

Is there any way of knowing what is the **actual** cause of this error ? Should I need to change something in thrift side  code ?

Comment: "*Should I need to change something in thrift side code ?*" - If you think you found an error in the Thrift code (be it generated or library), please file a JIRA ticket including a test case. If you have a patch proposal or an idea, include that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like this is a Thrift issue at all... it seems like it is inside the library that you are using ("twitter commons" or whatever).  I presume that their library is trying to create a dynamic proxy for your interface, but your interface it unable to handle whatever checked exception is being thrown.

You might want to try declaring "throws java.lang.Throwable" on your interface **temporarily** if you are having trouble ascertaining the underlying exception and are unable to fix the implementation of the Invocation Handler itself.  At least the root cause won't be buried by the `UndeclaredThrowableException` if you do that.

Alternatively, just set a breakpoint in a graphical debugger and step through the invocation to be able to see your program's state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that my client side thread was sending a `Thread.interrupt()` to the `myThriftClient` thread.

So in that case the `Caller` class (which in my case was `DeadlineCaller`) inside the `Thrift` class was interrupted which resulted in an `InterruptedException` or a `TimeoutException` which was bundled and displayed as `UndeclaredThrowableEception` in the stack.