# @Recover annotated method is not discovered for a @Retryable method that also is @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I studied the answer from this question [@Recover methods are not triggered with @Retryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897396/recover-methods-are-not-triggered-with-retryable?rq=1)

But I can't figure out why recover method does not run in my case.

```
@Service public MyRetryingService {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10 * 1000)
    @Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100, maxDelay = 101), maxAttempts = 3)
    public void transferData() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        System.out.println("Recovering from a service down");
    }
}
```

I get this exception

```
org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Cannot locate recovery method; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Spring Framework are you using?

It's a problem that was recently fixed [SPR-16196](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16196).

Comment: I am using spring boot 1.5.3 which seems to use spring core 4.3.8.RELEASE. Also please note that Retry method is performing retries as it should, but the Recover method is not called after 3 tries. I will try updating to the latest spring boot and see if that improves things. Thank you.

Comment: Updating to the latest version of spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE resolved my issue although the fix version mentioned in the issue would have been sufficient I think. Thank you.

Comment: The current 1.5.x version (1.5.10) uses SF 4.3.14, which includes the fix [see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L154). But moving to 2.0 is a good move anyway.