# Is it possible to throw checked exception in Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

Hello I'm trying to throw custom Exceptions from my @Aspect, but no matter what exception I throw, my Aspect is throwing **UndeclaredThrowableException**,

My custom exception is

```
public class AuthorizationException extends RuntimeException {
    public AuthorizationException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

And my Aspect is

```
@Around("@annotation(MyCustomAnnotation)")
    public Object validateAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp throws Throwable {

    // for testing purpose directly throwing
    throw new AuthorizationException("My custom error);
}
```

And I'm supposed to get **AuthorizationException** but I'm getting **UndeclaredThrowableException**

I have tried directly throwing RuntimeError from the **validateAspect** method and changed **throws Throwable** to **throws AuthorizationException** but still same. Tried to catch it with Global Exception handler as well but the custom string message is always null.

Comment: Please read through the [StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490372/4214241)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aspect is throwing a checked exception which is not declared in the intercepted method or one of its callers along the call stack. Unfortunately, you did not even post a stack trace, which is not very helpful. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is also missing, so I can only answer the question as generically as you were asking it.

Your claim that throwing a runtime exception makes an `UndeclaredThrowableException` appear is simply false, unless part of the application, e.g. another aspect or interceptor applied via dynamic proxies, catches that runtime exception and throws a checked exception instead. If you disagree, please prove your claim by editing your question and adding an MCVE or linking to one on GitHub.

Please read this tutorial in order to better understand your own situation:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-undeclaredthrowableexception

Comment: You are right, made a silly mistake by throwing raw Exception instead of throwing checked exceptions, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Let me correct your statement in order to avoid confusion for other readers: You mean, you threw a checked exception instead of a runtime exception. 