# How to interrupt JoinPoint execution in AOP

Tags: spring-aop, aspect

Is it possible to interrupt invoking the actual method from within the aspect execution?
For example:

```
public class CheckPermissionAspect {
  
  @Around("@annotation(CheckPermission)")
  public Object methodLogging( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  
    // before method execution
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    log.info("Enter ==> " + signature.getMethod().getName());
    
    if ( getPermission( principal.getName()) == false ) {

       // break the execution of actual method
       Object result = null; // ???
       log.info("Break ==> " + signature.getMethod().getName());
    } else {

       // invoke the actual method
       Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

       // after method execution
       log.debug("Result: " + result);
       log.info("Leave ==> " + signature.getMethod().getName());
    }


    
    return result;
  
  }
  
}
```

To set `Object result = null;` does not work.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: remove `Object result = joinPoint.proceed();` , that should stop the execution

Comment: Do go through [Around Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice).- *Within the body of the advice method, you must invoke proceed() on the ProceedingJoinPoint in order for the underlying method to run*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring Reference documentation : [Around Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)

> Within the body of the advice method, you must invoke proceed() on the
> ProceedingJoinPoint in order for the underlying method to run

If `joinPoint.proceed()` is removed from the code or an exception is thrown before `joinPoint.proceed()` statement or a `return` is issued before `joinPoint.proceed()` statement , the execution of the underlying method would get interrupted.

**Update : to answer the comment**

Spring AOP is proxy based. To understand this concept better , do read through : [Understanding AOP proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

An advice is placed between the calling method and the target. All calls to the target method gets intercepted and advised.

You could throw an exception upon validation ( Do note that the exception type thrown should match the exception type of the target method . Go through this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5490139/4214241)).

The exception/return value from the advise would reach back the calling method .

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And is it possible to handle the return value in the annotated method? For example: return "no permission for user xy"; in the AspectMethod. Where and how can I access the return value?

Comment: @jrg answer updated , please go through . If your question is answered , do mark this as answer and upvote if it helped.